# Как сделать чтобы при повторном нажатии элемент переворачивался?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Такой вопрос, есть блок который при наведении переворачивается(на пк), на мобильном устройстве он переворачиваться при клике.

Но проблема в том что он переворачивается только в одну сторону.

Как сделать чтобы элемент переворачивался при клике как в одну так и в другую сторону?

Вот этот элемент: [fitness.ad-rocket.com.ua/our-trainers](http://fitness.ad-rocket.com.ua/our-trainers)

```css
.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 648px;
}

.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<div class="ourtrainers">
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <div class="box1">
          <div class="trener-img ourtrainers-img"><img src="' . $image_url . '"></div>
          <div class="ourtrainers-title">' . $title . '</div>
          <div class="vc-infobox-texttitle ourtrainers-text">' . $texttitle . '</div>
          <div class="vc-infobox-texttitle">' . $experience . '</div>
          <div class="vc-infobox-texttitle">' . $workexperience . '</div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <div class="box2">
          <div class="ourtrainers-text-back">' . $text . '</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Здесь Javascript нужен. Нужно вешать обработчики событий на этот элемент.

Comment: Зачем тут JS? можно добавить элемент у которого есть 2 состояния, например checkbox, при клике пользователь будет менять его состояние, а в css уже будем поворачивать @Дмытрык

Comment: А Вы знаете, что в IE (даже 11) это работать не будет? На всякий случай предупреждаю, вдруг Вы не в курсе.

Comment: @lazyproger, интересно посмотреть на такую реализацию. Может у Вас есть ссылка?

Comment: @Дмытрык завтра если не забуду, скину пример

Comment: @humster_spb можно пруфы пожалуйста? я думал что ie10 поддерживает трансформации https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: @lazyproger, какие пруфы? просто откройте ссылку, которую дал автор вопроса, в IE, и всё увидите. Трансформация срабатывает, да, но нет эффекта оборотной стороны.

Comment: @humster_spb в ie10 все работает, зачем вы за блуждаете людей?

Comment: @lazyproger, что работает?! Вы понимаете, какая задача стоит? Не просто перевернуть картинку, а сделать оборотную сторону - чтобы там другое содержимое было. В IE картинка просто переворачивается - вывернутым наизнанку содержимым. Оборотной стороны там нет.

Comment: чекбоксы это костыль

Comment: @Duoxx у элемента есть 2 состояния, пользоваться этим, костыль?

Comment: Они не для этого были придуманы. А использовать что-либо в неправильном назначении плохой тон, только в безвыходных ситуациях которая кстати таковой не является.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.flip-container').click(function(){
  $('.flipper').toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

```css
.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.flip-container .flipper.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 648px;
}

.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ourtrainers">
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <div class="box1">
          <div class="trener-img ourtrainers-img"><img src="' . $image_url . '"></div>
          <div class="ourtrainers-title">' . $title . '</div>
          <div class="vc-infobox-texttitle ourtrainers-text">' . $texttitle . '</div>
          <div class="vc-infobox-texttitle">' . $experience . '</div>
          <div class="vc-infobox-texttitle">' . $workexperience . '</div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <div class="box2">
          <div class="ourtrainers-text-back">' . $text . '</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```